# CAR API Functions - AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic, traffic-simulation

I am using the AnyLogic traffic library and need to use two functions listed here: [CAR API](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/road-traffic-library/car.html), getDistanceDriven() and getLaneIndex(). But when I invoke them I get the error:  ***The method getDistanceDriven() is undefined for the type Vehicle, The method getLaneIndex() is undefined for the type Vehicle.***

*distance* is a parameter in Vehicle agent:

[image]

I don't have much experience with AnyLogic and I don't know if I am using the function well. Inside the list there is the function called getSpeed() but this one works fine. I have the AnyLogic 8 University version thinking it was some limitation of the PLE version but I have the same problem.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it like this:

[image]

Go to the project browser, click on the agent "Vehicle". In its properties, under the tab **Agent in flowcharts** change on **Use in flowcharts as**: to "Car".

Comment: This is correct, thx for posting it for future users as well. You "activate" car API functions with this setting, hence why it did not work before this.